# Freezing Indy HTTP. Get on Android Delphi 11 inside thread

Tags: android, http, delphi, indy

I recently migrate from Delph 10.2 to Delphi 11.
Base of this code I get http from server periodically inside thread.

```
  myth := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
    var IdHTTP1:TIdHTTP;
  begin

        ...
        ...
        IdHTTP1:=TIdHTTP.Create();
        IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) 
          Gecko/20100101Firefox/12.0';
        ...
        ...
        IdHTTP1.Get(Url,ResStm);
        ...
        ...

 end);
 myth.start
```

This code run on Delphi 10.2 without any freezing, but on a Delphi 11 freeze this line 'IdHTTP1.Get(Url,ResStm);' over 5 seconds.

Comment: Working fine here. You might want to show proper [mcve] as above code works fine. Make sure this is not server related issue.

Comment: If you assign a value < 5sec to `TIdHTTP.ConnectTimeout` and/or `TIdHTTP.ReadTimeout`, does it actually timeout? A freeze during DNS lookup before the TCP socket is even created/connected would not be accounted for by those properties. `ConnectTimeout` only applies to the initial establishment of the TCP connection once the target IP is known. `ReadTimeout` only applies while reading data from the TCP connection.

Comment: My actual code is very complicated  and I wrote a tested program for 'minimal-reproducible-example' and it is fine without any frizzed but on my code  have a delay on mention line and when I dim that line every thing is fine. I mention that on Delphi 10.2 no frozen occurs and that code without any change frizzed on running program on Delphi 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses of bad place for sync procedure for update content of form was reason of this freezing.

```
TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,procedure ()
  begin
    ....
    ...
    ...
  end);
```

By limit this enclose structure to some of necessary lines, freezing limited to
milliseconds and that is not noticeable.
for example: I placed  decompressing of stream outside of sync.

Finally mention that: this freezing occurs on **Delphi 11**